# Hide names in Highcharts Venn Diagram

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm drawing a Venn diagram using Highcharts and only want to show the names of the three main circles, not the intersections, i.e. just show reading, writing and maths.

[image]

I've tried setting 'name' to an empty string and NULL, but can't get it to work, though note on the fiddle setting name to "" does work for the intersection of all three circles (I think this is probably Highcharts deciding there isn't room to show it).

```
Highcharts.chart('report', {

  chart: {
    type: 'venn'
  },

  series: [{
    data: [{
      "name": ["Reading"],
      "sets": ["Reading"],
      "value": 100
    }, {
      "name": ["Writing"],
      "sets": ["Writing"],
      "value": 100
    }, {
      "name": ["Maths"],
      "sets": ["Maths"],
      "value": 100
    }, {
      "name": null,
      "sets": ["Reading", "Writing"],
      "value": 20
    }, {
      "name": "",
      "sets": ["Reading", "Maths"],
      "value": 20
    }, {
      "name": "",
      "sets": ["Writing", "Maths"],
      "value": 20
    }, {
      "name": "",
      "sets": ["Reading", "Writing", "Maths"],
      "value": 10
    }]
  }]
});
```

Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/4vg0d7ao/6/

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set name to an empty array:

```
Highcharts.chart('report', {    
  chart: {
    type: 'venn'
  },    
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{    
    data: [{
      "name": ["Reading"],
      "sets": ["Reading"],
      "value": 100
    }, {
      "name": ["Writing"],
      "sets": ["Writing"],
      "value": 100
    }, {
      "name": ["Maths"],
      "sets": ["Maths"],
      "value": 100
    }, {
      "name": [],
      "sets": ["Reading", "Writing"],
      "value": 20
    }, {
      "name": [],
      "sets": ["Reading", "Maths"],
      "value": 20
    }, {
      "name": [],
      "sets": ["Writing", "Maths"],
      "value": 20
    }, {
      "name": [],
      "sets": ["Reading", "Writing", "Maths"],
      "value": 10
    }]
  }]
});
```

Edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rLmd97n5/

Comment: Thank you - knew it would be something simple!